# How to get all custom labels information which is used in apex page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I want to get all custom labels through rest API. I used custom labels in apex page
like

> {!$Label.MyCustomLabel}

. So can i get information about **MyCustomLabel** through rest api.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really an easy way to get the custom labels out of an org. The CustomLabel/ExternalString object isn't queryable, and the `services/data/v43.0/nouns` part of the rest api doesn't include them either.

The only way to get custom labels from Salesforce right now is by reading metadata. The quickest way to do this would probably be to use the synchronous `listMetadata` and `readMetadata` calls. This uses the SOAP api, so there's a bit of XML involved here.

1., **`listMetadata`**, replace `org-id` with your org id, and replace `session-id` with your session id.

```
curl \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
-H 'SOAPAction: ""' \
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/38.0/org-id \
-d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header><n1:SessionHeader xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><n1:sessionId>session-id</n1:sessionId></n1:SessionHeader></env:Header><env:Body><n1:listMetadata xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><n1:queries><n1:type type="xsd:string">CustomLabel</n1:type></n1:queries></n1:listMetadata></env:Body></env:Envelope>'
```

2., pull out all of the custom label names within the `<fullName>` tags

3., **`readMetadata`**, replace `org-id` with your org id, replace `session-id` with your session id, and replace `custom-label-name` with the name of a custom label.

```
curl \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
-H 'SOAPAction: ""' \
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/38.0/org-id \
-d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header><n1:SessionHeader xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><n1:sessionId>session-id</n1:sessionId></n1:SessionHeader></env:Header><env:Body><n1:readMetadata xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><n1:type type="xsd:string">CustomLabel</n1:type><n1:fullNames type="xsd:string">custom-label-name</n1:fullNames><n1:fullNames type="xsd:string">custom-label-name</n1:fullNames></n1:readMetadata></env:Body></env:Envelope>'
```

Comment: Thanks martin, Its worked can you please share related document that is very useful for me.

Comment: @Shubham No problem. The best reference for this would be the [metadata api developers' guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/)

Answer (score -1):

try:
1 - from console, activate tooling api 
2 - query:

```
Select Id, name, masterlabel, ManageableState, Value 
FROM ExternalString
```